# CSS Overlay with Parallax

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created a web mockup with a few different parallax backgrounds.  The design calls for an overlay from the content within the parallax scroller to overlay they static element.  The easiest way to understand is to look at the demo site at: http://44a.a8b.myftpupload.com/

In the lower section you'll see profile pictures overlaying a dark brick parallax background.  The upper most profile pick is cut off instead of overlaying the content above.  I've played with all sorts of z-index and positions but can't seem to solve this one.

Help me Stackoverflow-Kenobi.... you're my only hope.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using following css on your page

```
.profiles {
    margin-top: -150px;
}
```

You should not use this or reduce this margin to `-100px` as follow:

```
.profiles {
   margin-top: -100px;
}
```

Try it will work perfect.

Comment: That will move the profiles into the parallax content area.  I want it to overlap the white container above, hence the extra 50px.  Currently it is tucked under the white container instead of being on top.

Comment: There is a CSS for this class `.hsContainer` remove `overflow:hidden;` from the css of this class it will work fine